# Woocommerce Subscription Renewal Issues

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, subscriptions, recurring

[image: Please see attached image.]

I have a question regarding Woocommerce Subscriptions recurring payment.
I need to know what the plugin means when it says to charge every 2nd week.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK I just answered this question myself.  Yes it means every 2 weeks.  So Oct 23, Nov 6, Nov 20, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some clarification for anyone else with a similar question, you can synchronize payments to specific days of the month or days of the week.

You can do this by first turning it on in Woocommerce > Settings > Subscriptions and ticking the box 'synchronize subscriptions'. Then you can adjust this per product.